# JPA Hibernate does not work on JBoss Fuse 6.0

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have been trying to deploy and run my camel route on the Jboss Fuse 6.0.
For the development I have been using JBoss Developer Studio and able to successfully run on my local machine.

But once I deploy the code to JBoss Fuse 6.0 it give a run time exception,
`

```
CaughtExceptionType:org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException, CaughtExceptionMessage:Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[null], StackTrace:org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[null] at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1342)`
```

Following are my configuration
camel-context.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mydb"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

From persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="mydb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<!--        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl -->
<!--        </provider> -->
        <!-- <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvide</provider>
 -->
        <class>some.database.model.DataModel</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=yes)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= some.database.hostname.com.au)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME= TESTIT)))" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="USER" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="PASS" />

            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->

            <!-- debugging flags -->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> <property name="hibernate.format_sql" 
                value="true"/> -->
        </properties>
```

Route code

```
         <route>
            <from uri="{{from.file.local.location}}" />
            <unmarshal ref="inputJaxb" />
            <bean ref="processXml" method="processXmlFile" />
            <to uri="log:insertLog" />
        </route>
```

and exception happens while executing this part of the code during run-time.

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory
                        .createEntityManager();
```

Can anyone please advise what I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Have you able to resolve this issue ? If so can you share the way of resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like persistence.xml is not being recognized by your bundle.
Please add *Meta-Persistence* instruction with value *META-INF/persistence.xml* in your pom.xml